# what is common GIS method?

Tags: gis

I want to know what is the main methods that used in GIS to connect between the location and their information (spatial access methodes) SAM.

I read in some web sites two methods are:

vector
raster

is that methods related  what I want???

thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

there are indeed in general two types of GIS datasources: Vector and Raster.

With vector; the attribute data can be stored in several ways:
- Side by side in a spatial database
- In a vector file paired with an attribute file (ESRI shape with ESRI dbf)
- Connected in an application (f.i. in MapInfo; connecting points to an excel sheet based upon a common attribute)

With raster; all you have is the numeric value of a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

The process of connecting data to geo-spatial coordinates is called [Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding).

Other common methods use simple coordinates (Lat/Long or GPS).

Vector/Raster refers to the two main types of graphical data that a GIS might use to render a map.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are thinking of is the WKT Geometry column.

In a data table where each row has one corresponding feature (point, line, segment, polygon,etc), there is usually a hidden GEOMETRY column, which consists of ***Well-Known Text (WKT)*** or ***Well-Known Binary (WKB)***. Polygons and lines are represented by all their vertex coordinates. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry.

[image]